# Kendo Scheduler - Add AutoComplete Search in Event Template

Tags: asp.net-mvc, autocomplete, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-scheduler

I'm using the Kendo Scheduler with resources for ASP.NET MVC, to manage the bookings in different fields of a sport center

The sport center has more tan one thousand customers, so I don't want to display a dropdownlist in my custom event template when I create a new booking

My idea is to display a nice autocomplete, so the manager can find a customer by typing the name or email of the customer.

The problem is I included some JavaScript to perform that in my CustomEditorTemplate.cshtml and I'm getting an Invalid template error. How can I fix this? I can't include javascript in the customs templates?

The autocomplete is working fine in other page, and the scheduler is working fine without the autocomplete code.

Thanks!

PS: I can include some code but I think it's irrelevant in this topic
​

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible, you can't edit directly the event on the scheduler. Instead why not considering adding the autocomplete on the editable template when you edit the event just like [this](http://dojo.telerik.com/uVanu), i tried to add kendo autocomplete on editable template and you can search while editing the event.

Comment: Yep! That work for me. I'm having another problem now (the results of the autocomplete are showing behind the popup) but that's another problem. Your answer is definitely the solution